# NuxtJS set Cookie in Middleware

Tags: javascript, cookies, nuxt.js

I'm building a nuxtjs app and try to set a cookie from a global middleware. I found [this](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2507#issuecomment-355518211) contribution on GitHub which shows a method to do this.

So I implemented my middleware like this

```
export default function ({ isServer, res, query }) {
  if (query.lang) {
    if (isServer) {
      res.setHeader("Set Cookie", [`lang=${query.lang}`]);
    } else {
        document.cookie = `lang=${query.lang}`;
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I visit my app with `?lang=xxx` as a parameter, I'm always running into the else block of my if condition. So I get the error

```
document is not defined
```

Has anyone a idea what is wrong with my code. I can't see a difference to the code published on github.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use [cookie-universal-nuxt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt).

Add this in your module section in `nuxt.config.js`:
`['cookie-universal-nuxt', { alias: 'cookiz' }],`

You can use it directly in the store with `nuxtServerInit`:

```js
async nuxtServerInit({ commit, state, dispatch },
    { app, store, route, req, res, error, redirect }
) {
    app.$cookiz.set('lang', route.query.lang)
})
```

Or in a middleware:

```js
export default function ({ app, res, query }) {
  if (query.lang) {
    app.$cookiz.set('lang', query.lang)
  }
}
```

Comment: i have faced an issue with nuxt production build, it simply won't set any cookies from a page or component

Answer (score 1):

In Nuxt 3 and Nuxt 2 Bridge you can use [`useCookie`](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-cookie/)

> Nuxt provides an SSR-friendly composable to read and write cookies.

```js
const lang = useCookie('lang')
lang.value = ''
```

Comment: This does not set cookies on the server side, only client-side, there is any way to set cookies on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can using helpers from nuxt by using setCookie and custom middleware
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware/

`middlewares/cookies.ts`

```js
export default function (req, res, next) {
 let cookie = getCookie(req, '_id') || 'random_value'
 setCookie(res, '_id', cookie)

// Don't forget to call next at the end if your middleware is not an endpoint
 next()
}
```

Also update your `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
export default defineNextConfig({
 // ...
 router: {
    middleware: ["cookies"],
 }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
export function getCookie(name, stringCookie) {
  const matches = stringCookie.match(
    new RegExp(
      `(?:^|; )${name.replace(/([.$?*|{}()[\]\\/+^])/g, '\\$1')}=([^;]*)`,
    ),
  );
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}
```

Comment: Consider Writing some text, explaining your answer.