# Can not set cookies for nuxtServerInit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, cookies, nuxt.js

I try to make login with faceboook feature, I am use rails for backend and nuxtjs for client, After I receive data from facebook and make user I want to redirect to client with `access_token` as authenticate, I want to save access_token to cookies, but on `nuxtServerInit` I can not make cookies. I also use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt for support cookies

```
export async function nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { store, route, req, res, app }) {
  if (route.query.token) {
    const token = `Bearer ${route.query.token}`
    store.commit(SET_STATE, { key: 'auth_info', value: { token: token } })
    this.$cookies.set('access_token', token)
  }
}
```

I inspect web to check cookies but no cookie is save on browsers. Anybody help me ?

I also read other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60336236/nuxtjs-set-cookie-in-middleware) but it does not work.

### Update:

I have resolve this problem by using `beforeNuxtRender`, I think nuxtServerInit is run before cookies set.

```
export async function nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { store, route, req, res, app, beforeNuxtRender }) {
  if (route.query.token) {
    const token = route.query.token
    let myProfile = null
    store.commit(SET_STATE, { key: 'auth_info', value: { token: token } })
    await store.dispatch('getUserProfile').then(res => {
      myProfile = res.data
      store.commit(SET_AUTH, { access_token: token, profile: myProfile })
    })
    beforeNuxtRender(({ nuxtState }) => {
      app.$cookies.set('access_token', token, { path: '/', maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 180 })
      app.$cookies.set('my_profile', myProfile, { path: '/', maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 180 })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Try app.$cookies.set instead of this.$cookies.set

Comment: remember: you cannot use `this` inside of `asyncData` or `nuxtServerInit`

Comment: Thanks but `app.$cookies.set` did not work for me :(

Comment: Confirm that function with "cookie-universal-nuxt" together worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have actually everything you need. You have the response object `res` so you can do:

```
export async function nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { store, route, req, res, app }) {
  if (route.query.token) {
    const token = `Bearer ${route.query.token}`
    store.commit(SET_STATE, { key: 'auth_info', value: { token: token } })
    res.cookie("access_token", token, {
      maxAge: 3600000,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I have see error `res.cookie is not a function`